# Angular 13 : 'mat-dialog-content' is not a known element

Tags: angular, import, dialog

I'd like to open a simple modal dialog inspired by the examples provided at https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/overview

I have a big angular-material-module.ts where I manage all the material imports:

```
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { OverlayModule } from '@angular/cdk/overlay';
import { CdkTreeModule } from '@angular/cdk/tree';
import { PortalModule } from '@angular/cdk/portal';
import { MatAutocompleteModule } from '@angular/material/autocomplete';
import { MatButtonModule } from '@angular/material/button';
import { MatButtonToggleModule } from '@angular/material/button-toggle';
import { MatCardModule } from '@angular/material/card';
import { MatCheckboxModule } from '@angular/material/checkbox';
import { MatChipsModule } from '@angular/material/chips';
import { MatRippleModule } from '@angular/material/core';
import { MatDividerModule } from '@angular/material/divider';
import { MatExpansionModule } from '@angular/material/expansion';
import { MatFormFieldModule } from '@angular/material/form-field';
import { MatIconModule } from '@angular/material/icon';
import { MatInputModule } from '@angular/material/input';
import { MatListModule } from '@angular/material/list';
import { MatMenuModule } from '@angular/material/menu';
import { MatPaginatorModule } from '@angular/material/paginator';
import { MatProgressSpinnerModule } from '@angular/material/progress-spinner';
import { MatSelectModule } from '@angular/material/select';
import { MatSidenavModule } from '@angular/material/sidenav';
import { MatSnackBarModule } from '@angular/material/snack-bar';
import { MatSortModule } from '@angular/material/sort';
import { MatTableModule } from '@angular/material/table';
import { MatTabsModule } from '@angular/material/tabs';
import { MatToolbarModule } from '@angular/material/toolbar';
import { MatTreeModule } from '@angular/material/tree';
import { MatBadgeModule } from '@angular/material/badge';
import { MatGridListModule } from '@angular/material/grid-list';
import { MatRadioModule } from '@angular/material/radio';
import { MatDatepickerModule } from '@angular/material/datepicker';
import { MatTooltipModule } from '@angular/material/tooltip';
import { MatSliderModule } from '@angular/material/slider';
import { MatDialogModule } from '@angular/material/dialog'; // <====

const materialModules = [
  CdkTreeModule,
  MatAutocompleteModule,
  MatButtonModule,
  MatCardModule,
  MatCheckboxModule,
  MatChipsModule,
  MatDividerModule,
  MatExpansionModule,
  MatIconModule,
  MatInputModule,
  MatListModule,
  MatMenuModule,
  MatProgressSpinnerModule,
  MatPaginatorModule,
  MatRippleModule,
  MatSelectModule,
  MatSidenavModule,
  MatSnackBarModule,
  MatSortModule,
  MatTableModule,
  MatTabsModule,
  MatToolbarModule,
  MatFormFieldModule,
  MatButtonToggleModule,
  MatTreeModule,
  OverlayModule,
  PortalModule,
  MatBadgeModule,
  MatGridListModule,
  MatRadioModule,
  MatDatepickerModule,
  MatTooltipModule,
  MatSliderModule,
  MatDialogModule,  // <===========
];
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    ...materialModules  // <==========
  ],
  exports: [
    ...materialModules  // <==========
  ],
})
export class AngularMaterialModule { }
```

and my app.module.ts looks like this :

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';

import { AngularMaterialModule } from './angular-material.module'; // <============
import { LoginComponent } from './login/login.component';
import { DashboardComponent } from './dashboard/dashboard.component';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    LoginComponent,
    DashboardComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    AngularMaterialModule, // <========
    FormsModule,
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

My dashboard component code loke like this :

```
import { Component, ViewChild, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import {MatSnackBar } from '@angular/material/snack-bar';

import {MatDialog} from '@angular/material/dialog'; // <==========
import {MatMenuTrigger} from '@angular/material/menu';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-dashboard',
  templateUrl: './dashboard.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./dashboard.component.css']
})
export class DashboardComponent implements OnInit {
  @ViewChild('menuTrigger') menuTrigger!: MatMenuTrigger;

  constructor(private router: Router, private snackBar: MatSnackBar, public dialog: MatDialog) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.snackBar.open("Test", "Close");
  }

  onInfo(): void {
    const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(UserInfoDialog, {restoreFocus: false});

    // Manually restore focus to the menu trigger since the element that
    // opens the dialog won't be in the DOM any more when the dialog closes.
    dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(() => this.menuTrigger.focus());
  }

  onLogout(): void {
    this.router.navigateByUrl("/login");
  }

}

@Component({
  selector: 'user-info-dialog',
  templateUrl: 'user-info-dialog.html',
})
export class UserInfoDialog {}
```

And user-info-dialog.html looks like this :

```
<mat-dialog-content>
    This is a dialog
</mat-dialog-content>
<mat-dialog-actions>
    <button mat-button mat-dialog-close>Okay</button>
</mat-dialog-actions>
```

After saving files, the Visual Code Debugger says for file user-info-dialog.html :

(element) mat-dialog-content: HTMLElement
'mat-dialog-content' is not a known element:

1. If 'mat-dialog-content' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'mat-dialog-content' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.ngtsc(-998001)
   dashboard.component.ts(6, 22): Error occurs in the template of component UserInfoDialog.

Solution 1 seems already ok (app.module.ts imports), I tried solution 2 without success...

What am I missing ?

Thank you.

Note :
ng --version output :

```
ng --version

     _                      _                 ____ _     ___
    / \   _ __   __ _ _   _| | __ _ _ __     / ___| |   |_ _|
   / △ \ | '_ \ / _` | | | | |/ _` | '__|   | |   | |    | |
  / ___ \| | | | (_| | |_| | | (_| | |      | |___| |___ | |
 /_/   \_\_| |_|\__, |\__,_|_|\__,_|_|       \____|_____|___|
                |___/


Angular CLI: 13.3.3
Node: 16.14.2
Package Manager: npm 8.5.0
OS: linux x64

Angular: 13.3.3
... animations, cdk, cli, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core
... forms, material, platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic
... router

Package                         Version
---------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect       0.1303.3
@angular-devkit/build-angular   13.3.3
@angular-devkit/core            13.3.3
@angular-devkit/schematics      13.3.3
@schematics/angular             13.3.3
rxjs                            7.5.5
typescript                      4.6.3
```

Comment: Does it compile in the terminal? Sometimes VS Code has a hard time figuring out where some of the html tags are coming from so you'll see some entries in the "probems" window, but the compiler can figure it out, so the program will run just fine.

Comment: @ShanieMoonlight no, the same error is returned

Comment: Are you running "ng serve"?

Comment: @ShanieMoonlight yes

Comment: What happens if you skip the AngularMaterialModule and just import the DialogModule directly?

Comment: @ShanieMoonlight same error :(

Comment: Have you installed angular/material? IS there something like this in:  "@angular/material": "^11.0.0", in your package.json ?

Comment: "@angular/material": "^13.3.3", in my package.json

Comment: That's the most recent version. Have you tried an earlier version?

Comment: @ShanieMoonlight no, you think it's a version bug ?

Comment: Maybe, I'm using ^11 and I'm not getting that error.

Comment: Same error on ^12, there's something that I miss...

Answer (score 2):

Found the problem!

I had to add `UserInfoDialog` to `@NgModule.declarations`

Comment: Easy mistake to make.